# Is testing authorization in an authorized namespace overkill?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an `admin` namespace that only permits admins access. Authentication is setup through a JWT token using the [knock gem](https://github.com/nsarno/knock) and a before action is called from a base controller:

```
class Api::Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin
end
```

---

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/'  do
  post 'admin-token', to: 'admin_token#create'

  namespace :admin do
    resources :restaurants
    ...
  end
end
```

As I'm setting up my request specs I'm wondering if I should writing a test in every individual REST action for each and every endpoint in order to check for authorization? Example:

```
RSpec.describe Restaurant, type: :request do
  describe 'GET /admin/restaurants' do
    context "when the request contains an authentication header" do
      get api_admin_restaurants_url, headers: authenticated_header

      it { expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok) }
    end

   context "when the request doesn't contain an authentication header" do
     get api_admin_restaurants_url

     expect(response).to have_http_status(:unauthorized)
   end
  end
end
```

Would something like this be advised since this entire namespace requires authorization to begin with?

Comment: I would simply test that your authorization works and acts as expected, that `Api::Admin::BaseController` calls `before_action :authenticate_admin`, that `authenticate_admin` acts as expected, and that each controller in your admin namespace inherits from `Api::Admin::BaseController`

Comment: Okay. If I follow you correctly, are you suggesting creating a test within the `base_controller` for this?

Comment: I think this is a matter of opinion, and I don't think there is a absolute right answer for that. But I would ask, what is the reason to NOT test it though? If you don't want to rewrite the same test again and again, you could simply leverage `shared_examples`. If that is not too much of a performance hit, I would rather be safe than sorry.